# Python: concatenate columns based on column with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like below:

```py
df
      A    B     C    D    E    key
0  test    Z  10.0    a    a  10111
1  test    A  10.0    a    a  10111
2  test    x   2.0    a    b  11010
3  test    5  12.0    b    b  10100
4  test    x   5.0    c    b  11000
5  test    2  14.0    g    c  10111
```

What I need to get is to concatenate all strings accordingly to `key` column:

- `key` at position `[0]` is for `col A`, `key` at position `[1]` is for `col B` and so on...
- each `1` in is for take, each `0` is for skip column

Result should look like:

```py
      A    B     C    D    E    key     key_val
0  test    Z  10.0    a    a  10111  test10.0aa
1  test    A  10.0    a    a  10111  test10.0aa
2  test    x   2.0    a    b  11010      testxa
3  test    5  12.0    b    b  10100    test12.0
4  test    x   5.0    c    b  11000       testx
5  test    2  14.0    g    c  10111  test14.0gc
```

What I did so far - I've created key_list column with:

```py
df['key_list'] = df['key'].apply(lambda x: list(str(x)))

df
      A  B     C  D  E    key         key_list
0  test  Z  10.0  a  a  10111  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
1  test  A  10.0  a  a  10111  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
2  test  x   2.0  a  b  11010  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
3  test  5  12.0  b  b  10100  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
4  test  x   5.0  c  b  11000  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
5  test  2  14.0  g  c  10111  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Next step I've tried this (I wanted to multiply by 1 or 0 to include or exclude string):

```py
df.apply((df['A'].astype(str) * df['key_list'][0]) +
         (df['B'].astype(str) * df['key_list'][1]) +
         (df['C'].astype(str) * df['key_list'][2]) +
         (df['D'].astype(str) * df['key_list'][3]) +
         (df['E'].astype(str) * df['key_list'][4]), axis=1)
```

but that seems to be wrong idea: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (5,)`. I follow common practice of string concatenation, just with extra step:

```py
df['A'].astype(str) + df['B'].astype(str) + df['C'].astype(str) + df['D'].astype(str) + df['E'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is convert `key` column to mask, then replace not match by empty string in [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and sum together for `join`:

```
c = ['A','B','C','D','E']

L = [list(str(x)) for x in df['key']]
m = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=c, index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(bool)
print (m)
      A      B      C      D      E
0  True  False   True   True   True
1  True  False   True   True   True
2  True   True  False   True  False
3  True  False   True  False  False
4  True   True  False  False  False
5  True  False   True   True   True

df['key_val'] = df[c].where(m, '').astype(str).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
      A  B     C  D  E    key     key_val
0  test  Z  10.0  a  a  10111  test10.0aa
1  test  A  10.0  a  a  10111  test10.0aa
2  test  x   2.0  a  b  11010      testxa
3  test  5  12.0  b  b  10100    test12.0
4  test  x   5.0  c  b  11000       testx
5  test  2  14.0  g  c  10111  test14.0gc
```